# Graphics glitch in QLabel (showing clipped character)

Tags: c++, c++11, qlabel, qt4.8

I'm working on an Qt app (**Qt 4.8** version) running on a Linux target.
This app uses QLabel to display some values (such as hourmeter).
The size of the `QLabel` varies depending on the value to display.

The problem is that sometimes the last character of the `QLabel` gets glitched.
I don't know how to reproduce it.

[image]

Here is the part of the code that manages this `QLabel`:

```
QFont DigitsFont;
DigitsFont.setPixelSize(48);
DigitsFont.setFamily("SquareRoundMono");

QLabel * lblValue = new QLabel(this);
lblValue->setFont(DigitsFont);

float tmpReal = externalValue;
tmpReal /= 3600; //seconds converted to hours

// Saturate to 99999.9h if horameter goes higher
if(tmpReal > 99999.9f)
{
    tmpReal = 99999.9f;
    DigitsFont.setPixelSize(36);
}
else if(tmpReal > 9999.9f)
    DigitsFont.setPixelSize(36);
else if(tmpReal > 999.9f)
    DigitsFont.setPixelSize(43);
else
    DigitsFont.setPixelSize(48);

lblValue->setFont(DigitsFont);
lblValue->setText(tmpStr.setNum(tmpReal,'f',1));
```

It seems that playing with the size and the value of a `QLabel` with this specific font can lead to this kind of bug.

Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem?